# Error only when running on actual phone (not emulator)

Tags: android, android-emulator

Making my app in Android Studio, I've been mostly running/testing it on the emulator.  Well I'm pretty much done with it(I think), and I ran it on my phone, which I've done before much earlier on.  Now when I get to one of my activities, I'm supposed to select a number of questions (quiz app) for a practice test I want to take, and hit "begin".  On my actual phone, this sends an error and brings up a message that the app has unfortunately stopped working.  The app then resets.

```
       02-26 10:42:16.458      964-964/godwin.com.study E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       Process: godwin.com.study, PID: 964
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3999)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4753)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19562)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3994)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4753)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19562)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.Intent.putExtra(Intent.java:6193)
        at godwin.com.study.chooseTestLength.sendLengthOnClick(chooseTestLength.java:57)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3994)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4753)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19562)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's the java/activity file that crashes when the button is pressed:

```
package godwin.com.study;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Spinner;


public class chooseTestLength extends ActionBarActivity {

public static String TEST_LENGTH;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_test_length);
}




public void sendLengthOnClick (View view){

    //Create new activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, takeTest.class);

    //Get spinner selection
    final Spinner choiceSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.testLengthSpinner);
    int num = Integer.parseInt(choiceSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

    intent.putExtra(TEST_LENGTH, num);
    startActivity(intent);
}


}
```

Here's the XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"
android:background="@color/background"
tools:context="godwin.com.study.chooseTestLength">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chooseLength"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/chooseLengthText"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/testLengthSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/testLength"
        android:entries="@array/testLengthChoice"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSendLength"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/startTest"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:onClick="sendLengthOnClick"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is at chooseTestLength.java:57 (found in your crash log)

Comment: I edited the question to include the java file relevant to the question.

Comment: I think there's something missing in you code. I can't see when sendLengthOnClick is called... but by the error message, I bet TEST_LENGTH variable is null when "intent.putExtra(TEST_LENGTH, num);" is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're either passing in a NULL value in the `Intent.putExtra()` method called from the `godwin.com.study.chooseTestLength.sendLengthOnClick()` function on line 57 or the Intent itself is NULL. Please post some code to better assess the issue.

EDIT:

As already stated, `TEST_LENGTH` is NULL. Give it a value like this:

```
public static String TEST_LENGTH = "TEST_LENGTH";
```

Intent extras work as key/value pairs. TEST_LENGTH is your key, and num is your value. Keys can not be NULL. Values can sometimes be NULL depending on the object type.

Comment: Hey I just did, was there anything else you needed to assess the issue?

Comment: I just saw that, but now I'm curious why it works on the emulator like I intended.  I thought the `putExtra` takes a variable name and a value as parameters.  So `TEST_LENGTH` is the variable name, and `num` holds the value so that I can use `getExtra` in the next activity that's called.  If this isn't the case, how am I supposed to use the `putExtra` and `getExtra` methods?

Comment: Ah, I see your edited code now.  I tried it and it worked!  Though, I really wish I understood why that's the case that it worked in the emulator and not the phone, but how adding that allows it to work on both now.  All the same, thank you very much.

Comment: In the Activity that you are starting you can get the value you're passing by calling getIntent().getExtra(chooseTestLength.TEST_LENGTH)(usually in the onCreate() method) and store it in that new Activity if needed or use it right away.

Comment: Right, I had done this previously.  Like I said, the app worked on the emulator, just not the phone when I ran it on my Galaxy S4.  So, while it works now on both, I still don't understand why it previously worked on one and not the other.  I implemented the getExtra and putExtra correctly the first time.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that it would work on the emulator. I'm afraid I don't have an answer for you there. I do know that the default emulator has some strange issues though. I was forced to leave the default one behind due to how slow it is when rendering OpenGL graphics. You might want to try [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) or [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/)